# Wordpress list parent page and childs

Tags: wordpress

i use the following code in my theme. The code shows me the title, thumb and link from childpages of page 176. I want that it not only show the childpages but also the content from 176. Perhaps its better to use get_pages or wp_list_pages but a solution for the wp_query would be nice. Thx for your help.

```
function sd_recent() {
global $post;
$this_post = $post->ID;

// args
$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'page',
'post_parent'   => 176  
);

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>

            <ul class="recent-links">
            <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>        

                <li <?php if( $this_post == $post->ID ) { echo ' class="current-recent-links"'; } ?>>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                        <span class="recent-links-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>           
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the parent content to appear once outside the loop, you could do this...

```
global $post;
if ($post->post_parent) {
    $parent = get_page($post->post_parent);
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $parent->post_content);
}
```

If you want it to appear each time within the loop, you would assign the parent content to a var and echo it within the loop.